# Max of Date with distinct ID

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, duplicates

I have a query involved 7 tables (but i think the main issue is on [tbl_Records]

Table setup:

**qry_CofC**: [ID], [Desc], [Maker], [Model], [S_N], [Tolerance], [Location], [Calibration Freq]

**tbl_Instruments**:[Remark]

**tbl_Records**: [Cal_Date], [Path]

**tbl_Unit**: [Unit]

**tbl_Status**: [txt_Status]

**tbl_Category**: [Category]

**tbl_Used_By**: [Name]

below is a snapshot of the query without [tbl_Records.Path]
[[image]

But When I add in [tbl_Records.Path], duplicated records appears
[image]
Here is my sql:

```
SELECT
    qry_CofC.ID, [tbl_Instruments].[Type] & "-" & [tbl_Instruments].[Item] AS Tool_ID,
    tbl_Unit.Unit, tbl_Status.txt_Status AS Status,
    tbl_Category.Category, tbl_Used_By.Name AS Used_By,
    Max(tbl_Records.Cal_Date) AS MaxOfCal_Date,
    Max(DateAdd("d",[qry_CofC]![Lead],(DateAdd("m",[qry_CofC]![Calibration Freq],[tbl_Records]![Cal_date])))) AS Due_Date,
    Max(DateDiff("d",Date(),DateAdd("d",[qry_CofC]![Lead],DateAdd("m",[qry_CofC]![Calibration Freq],[tbl_Records]![Cal_date])))) AS Due,
    tbl_Instruments.Remark,
    tbl_Records.Path
FROM tbl_Unit
    INNER JOIN (tbl_Status
        INNER JOIN (tbl_Used_By
            INNER JOIN (tbl_Category
                INNER JOIN (tbl_Tol
                    INNER JOIN ((qry_CofC INNER JOIN tbl_Instruments ON qry_CofC.[ID] = tbl_Instruments.[ID])
                    INNER JOIN tbl_Records ON tbl_Instruments.[ID] = tbl_Records.[Inst_ID])
                    ON tbl_Tol.ID = tbl_Instruments.Accuracy)
                ON tbl_Category.ID = tbl_Instruments.Category)
            ON tbl_Used_By.ID = tbl_Instruments.Used_By_Operator)
        ON tbl_Status.Index = tbl_Instruments.Status)
    ON tbl_Unit.ID = tbl_Instruments.Unit

GROUP BY qry_CofC.ID, [tbl_Instruments].[Type] & "-" & [tbl_Instruments].[Item], tbl_Unit.Unit, tbl_Status.txt_Status, tbl_Category.Category, tbl_Used_By.Name, tbl_Instruments.Remark, tbl_Records.Path

ORDER BY [tbl_Instruments].[Type] & "-" & [tbl_Instruments].[Item];
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: try using a last or subquery to do this, it will be easier for you to read up on sub queries.

Comment: Sorry I am still kinda new to sql, Do you mind if you guide my through subquery? "Last" does not give me the result i wanted :( @Nathan_Sav

Comment: That's why I said it's best for you to read them, understand them

Comment: Yeah yeah, but where should i begin from? @Nathan_Sav

Comment: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html is a good place to start

Comment: Also, have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT ...` or `LEFT JOIN tbl_Records ...` (instead of `INNER JOIN`)? Also check if the fields you are joining this table on are have unique values in both tables.